# What are the Open Source Mature Equivalent of Amazon CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I would like not to tight with aws technologies and I was wondering what are the Open Source Mature Equivalent of Amazon CloudFront?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDN is not some software which can have open-source.. It is a network of computers ( POPs ) i.e. lots of hardware, server, bandwidths are needed to implement a CDN. Hence, open source is not possible.
Regarding getting tied up with AWS; all you need to do is create a different URL suppose for all media URLS like http://cdn.example.com .. And all the static content which should be served via CDN should be put on this URL.. something like http://cdn.example.com/abc.jpg 
Now, you can just create A records, B records on your DNS server to point to Amazon Cloud Front.. if suppose tomorrow you want to switch your cloud front; all you need to do is change these records on dns server.. Thats it. You are in no way tied with amazon.